# Isomorphism between localizations of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and ideal $\langle 2, 1 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle$ at some prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

I am working through the problems in Dummit and Foote and can't seem to work out (or even begin to start) 15.4.15(c) (p.727):

> Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ be the ring of integers in the quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ and let $I$ be the prime ideal $(2, 1 + \sqrt{-5})$ of $R$ generated by $2$ and $1 + \sqrt{-5}$. Recall that every nonzero prime ideal $P$ of $R$ contains a prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$.
>
> (c) Prove that $I_P \cong R_P$ as $R_P$-modules for every prime ideal $P$ of $R$ but that $I$ and $R$ are not isomorphic $R$-modules.

It appears that we can begin by showing that if $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$ not containing 2, then $I_P = R_P$

And furthermore, if $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$ containing 2 then $P=I$ and $I_P = (1+ \sqrt{-5})R_P$. This is as the authors and Trevor suggest. However, I am unsure of how to do this.

Comment: You meant the localization at $P$ not $(p)$, ie. $R_P = \{ \frac{a}{b}, a \in R, b \in R \setminus P\}$. Then it is a local ring (with unique maximal ideal which is principal) and $I_P$ is an ideal.

Comment: @reuns Both are modules, and the OP asks for module's isomorphism.

Comment: Ideal of $S$ and $S$-submodule is the same thing.  @eranreches The second part asks for $P$ being a principal ideal or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $P \ne I$ you should be able to show that $I_P = R_P$. When $P = I$ then $I_I$ is the maximal ideal of the DVR $R_I$. In a DVR the maximal ideal is principal so $I_I = \pi R_I$ for some element $\pi$. As an $R_I$-module, this is isomorphic to $R_I$ via the map $x \mapsto \pi x$.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that we can show that if $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$ not containing 2, then $I_P = R_P$. And furthermore, if $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$ containing 2 then $P=I$ and $I_P = (1+ \sqrt{-5})R_P$. This is just as you suggest, but how would one actually go about this?

Comment: @JeffreyAnonemheiser How to show that $I_P = R_P$? You need to show that $I_P$ contains a unit. What are the units of $R_P$?

Comment: Also the second part of the question is useful for the first part : if $J$ is an ideal of $S$, then $J \cong S$ as $S$-modules iff $J$ is a non-zero principal ideal.

Comment: @JeffreyAnonemheiser Your argument is correct but I don't think it's the best property to exploit. If $I$ doesn't contain a unit in $R_P$ that means that every element of $I$ is contained in $P$ ($I \subseteq P$), but in $R$ the nonzero prime ideals prime ideals are maximal so this means that $I = P$. This lets you avoid breaking into cases of whether or not $P$ contains $2$. Now, I'm going to bed soon so if you have any other questions you can either wait until tomorrow or create a new question.

Comment: @JeffreyAnonemheiser Just show it is an isomorphism the way you always do. It is surjective because every element of $\pi R_P$ is of the form $\pi x$ for some $x \in R_P$. It is injective because if $\pi x = \pi y$ then $x = y$ ($R_P$ is an integral domain). Etc.

Comment: Right. I had showing the map is bijective settled. I was wondering how to show that it's an $R_P$-module homomorphism. Is it as easy as claiming $\pi$ is distributive? Thanks, @TrevorGunn

Comment: @JeffreyAnonemheiser Yeah, you're just distributing $\pi(x + y) = \pi x + \pi y$ and using associativity/commutativity $\pi (r x) = r (\pi x)$.